# fullscreen modal fade not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm working on multiple fullscreen modals on one page, but i can't seem to get them just to fade in. Instead they slide in/out under an angle. I'm trying to get them to just fade in/out instead of sliding, to no avail.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mk9ek9wt/

html

```
    <li> <a href="#" class="open" data-target='A1'>test1</a></li>
     <li> <a href="#" class="open" data-target='A2'>test2</a></li>     



<div class="container A1">
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    </p>
    <p class="changeText">
content 1
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container A2">
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    </p>
    <p class="changeText">
content 2 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

css

```
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-opacity:.60;
    opacity:.60;
    display:none;

}
.container {
    position:fixed!important;
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    margin:-100px 0px 0px -200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color:white;
    display:none;
    z-index:1002;
    padding:10px;
}
```

js

```
 $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.open').click(
            function() {
                var target=$(this).data('target');
                $('.overlay').show('slow',
                    function() {
                        $('.container.'+target).fadeIn('slow');

                    }
                );
            }
        );
         $('.close').click(
            function() {
                $(this).parents('.container').hide('slow',
                     function() {
                          $('.overlay').fadeOut();          
                     }    
                );
            }
        );  
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeIn on .overlay

```
$('.overlay').fadeIn('slow',
    function() {
        $('.container.'+target).fadeIn('slow');
    }
);
```

and .container

```
$(this).parents('.container').fadeOut('slow',
    function() {
        $('.overlay').fadeOut();          
    }    
);
```